# How to split the string,integer etc and count it in java?

Tags: java, io, split, count

I already make a simple program as a divider a value. Now, I have three files in my project. its kompil.java, input.txt, output.txt.

I want input.txt as a source input and output.txt to print out it. But, it should be a counter each type value of it.

This is my input.txt:

```
Z=((2+B)250+B-A+MN)/2-256*10
```

And I want the output in output.txt like this:

```
VARIABLE
Z:1
B:2
A:1
MN:1

OPERATOR
(:2
):2
+:3
=:1
-:2
/:1
*:1

NUMBER
2:2
250:1
256:1
10:1
```

But, I dont know how to make output like that. I have ever try a split method but. Stuck.
Please give me any Idea for this.

And here is my code of kompil.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class kompil {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String fileName = "src/input.txt";
        String line = null;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = 
                    new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
char[] chars=line.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
String out = new String(chars);
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("src/output.txt");
                PrintStream orig = System.out;
                System.setOut(ps);
                System.out.println(out);
                System.setOut(orig);
                ps.close();
            }   
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to open file '" + 
                    fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error reading file '" 
                    + fileName + "'"); 
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to continue the code?

Comment: You didn't actually provide the code.

Comment: Please post your code _directly_ to SO.

Comment: I couldn't paste my code in above. This is my first time for question. I dont understand for the rules. Can you advie me, please?

Comment: Your existing code looks like it is trying to write the input file to the output file. What ideas have you had about implementing your requirement?

Comment: Hi jason, I just try to use the array to implementing. And I don't know, how to split it by char right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are already splitting it to characters in the line `char[] chars=line.toCharArray();`.  Do not sort that array (see your next line).  Instead, this is where you apply what you learned in the classroom.  Take a good look at the static functions of the Character class, like Character.isDigit(char) to interpret each character, and perhaps the ArrayList object for keeping track of each type of token you identify.